# How to create Projection based on other content type value in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am trying to use Projection Query in orchard to filter my Projection based on the current Page. Right now I have a contentItem with a field called PageName which I am trying to match the value of. Can this be achieved using projections? I know that Tokens doesn't work in this scenario. What would be the best step of achieving what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokens is well suited for this scenario.

Get current content item by token:

```
{Request.Content}
```

Get field by token:

```
{Content.Fields.YourPartName.PageName}
```

By combining these two tokens you can get what you need:

```
{Request.Content.Fields.YourPartName.PageName}
```

You can find token 1 and 2 in the drop-down list of tokens when you edit query filter.